# .NET Gmail OAuth Service Passing Incorrect/Inconsistent RedirectURI

Tags: .net, .net-core, gmail-api

I'm following the [.NET Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet) for the Gmail API to add an integration to my .NET Core 2.2 application.

For some reason, the `Redirect URI` being specified in my request is *not* the one I've specified.

**credentials.json**

```
{
  "web": {
    //redacted,
    "redirect_uris": [ "https://localhost:44393/ExternalAuth/Gmail" ]
  }
}
```

**Credentials Dashboard**

[image: credentials]

---

[image]

---

**Code**

```
UserCredential credential;

using (var stream = new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
  string credPath = "token.json";
  credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
    Scopes,
    "user",
    CancellationToken.None,
    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)
  ).Result;
  Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
}
```

I can't seem to find where it's getting this from; I assume it's just pulling it from my local machine, though I imagine there must be a way to override the URI being included in the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue.

When creating the OAuth credentials in Google, the application type should be ***Desktop***, not *Web Application*.

[image]

After doing so, you should notice that your `credentials.json` file begins with `installed:` instead of `web:`.